# Number Validation in Wicket

Tags: wicket

I am using wicket 1.5. I have text field where in the user enters the amount and that "amount" i am using in wicket class for furthur purpose. I need to validate the amount field

```
final TextField<Integer> amount = new TextField<Integer>("amount",Integer.class);
```

If i use as above validation is done but i am not able to get the amount value in the class 
Whether there are any other methods to validate

Regards
Sharath

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what's the question here but a [NumberTextField](http://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/apidocs/1.5.x/org/apache/wicket/markup/html/form/NumberTextField.html) could by your answer.

From the JavaDoc

> Automatically validates the input against the configured {@link #setMinimum(Number) min} and {@link #setMaximum(Number) max} attributes. If any of them is `null` then {@link Double#MIN_VALUE} and {@link Double#MAX_VALUE} are used respectfully.

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting the textfield in a form by the onSubmit method, just chck the value by

textfield.getModelObject();

compare it with whatever you need and if it doesnt match send a feedback error, what do you think?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is one more way you can validate the text field input. TextField component provides you with an add() method where you can add wicket validation rule. For example you can write your custom rule which implements IValidator interface of wicket.

You can find various in built wicket validators here : http://wicket.apache.org/apidocs/1.4/org/apache/wicket/validation/validator/package-summary.html

To answer your question about getting the value that user inputs in the text field, if you have this text field in any form then onSubmit of this form you should be able to get the value by calling

```
    amount.getModelObjet();
```

Hope this answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, Wicket expects you to pass a model (getter+setter as an object) to the component and uses that to store the converted result.

You should be able to use textField.getConvertedInput() to get the value in case you don't want to use a model. But doing this is rather the exception because you end up copying that value to its destination anyway, which the model would automate for you.